# R - How to integrate if any in dplyr?

Tags: r, medical, data-cleaning

I am working on claims data which looks like the below format :-

```
claim  mem_number  year_month  label
 1      123         2011-Jan   Clinic
 2      123         2011-Jan   Lab
 3      123         2011-Jan   Office
 4      234         2011-Jan   office
 5      234         2012-Feb   Lab
```

I would like to group by mem_number and year_month and covert all those labels to clinics even if a single label in that group is clinic.The output should be :-

```
Claim  mem_number  year_month  label
 1      123         2011-Jan   Clinic
 2      123         2011-Jan   Clinic
 3      123         2011-Jan   Clinic
 4      234         2011-Jan   Office
 5      234         2012-Feb   Lab
```

My approach to this problem is :-

```
library("dplyr")

output<-input %>% group_by(mem_number,year_month) %>%
        mutate(label=if(any(label=="Clinic","Clinic",NA)))
```

Its giving me errors. I would like to know my mistake and how to resolve it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `if(any(label=="Clinic")) "Clinic" else NA` or maybe you wanted `ifelse()`

Comment: Like Richard said, You havn't closed the `any` parenthesis neither the `if` ones in the right place. And you used the `ifelse` syntax on an `if` and `else`- which are different functions. Try something like `mutate(label = ifelse(any(label == "Clinic"), "Clinic", as.character(label)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Tried your code! It works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`, I'd do it like this:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dt[dt[label == "Clinic"], label := "Clinic", on="mem_number"]
```

We extract those rows where `label == "Clinic"`. This allows us to use `mem_number` corresponding to those rows. And we perform a join on those rows back on `dt`, and for each matching rows, we update `label` with the value `"Clinic"`.

As @Frank points out, if you'd like the join to be instead on `mem_number` and `year_month`, just use `on=c("mem_number", "year_month")`. I did not think it was necessary for the example you've shown.

Comment: I get this error - 'Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, dt[label == "INPATIENT_SURGERY"], `:=`(label,  : 
  unused argument (on = c("MEM_NUMBER", "Year_Month"))'

Comment: Curious, there is an `index` attribute in the result.  What is that?  It is `index = integer(0)` in the `dput()` and `$index` in the attributes.  Haven't seen that before.  Feel free to answer here or in the chat room.  We're discussing it in GMTs.

Comment: Richard, auto indexing `label` column due to `== "Clinic"`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

bad_rows <- DT[, 
  if (any(label=="Clinic")) .I[label != "Clinic"]
, by=.(mem_number,year_month)]$V1

DT[ bad_rows, label := "Clinic" ]
```

or

```
bad_groups <- DT[, 
  if (any(label=="Clinic")) 1
, by=.(mem_number,year_month)][, V1 := NULL]

DT[ bad_groups, label := "Clinic", on=c("mem_number", "year_month")]
```

---

**Comment.** I think it would be clearer if we could write

```
# pseudocode -- DOES NOT WORK
DT[, 
  label[label != "Clinic"] := "Clinic"
, by=.(mem_number, year_month), having = any(label=="Clinic")]
```

but feature requests for this are still open.

Comment: @x1carbon Oh, just noticed that you asked for dplyr in the title. Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for, and please next time remember to add it to your tags.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. More methodologies are always welcome. Appreciate it.